# Why is Uri.ToString() encoding spaces differently depending on input string?

Tags: c#, uri, spaces

I have a problem with the encoding of spaces when I use ToString() on an Uri in C#, it seems to behave differently depending on the input string.
Here's my snippet of code:

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("root");  
sb1.Append("/");
sb1.Append(System.Uri.EscapeDataString("something with spaces"));
Uri result1 = new System.Uri(sb1.ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
// result1.ToString() returns "root/something%20with%20spaces"

StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("root");  
sb2.Append("/");
sb2.Append(System.Uri.EscapeDataString("something with spacés and accènts")); // "root/something%20with%20spac%C3%A9s%20and%20acc%C3%A8nts"
Uri result2 = new System.Uri(sb2.ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
// result2.ToString() returns "root/something with spacés and accènts"
```

I don't get it. Is it because it tries to find the encoding on each input string and finds a different one because of the accents?

**EDIT**

The code above is just an example I tried running in the Immediate Window, the real code snippet is in a getter of a Uri parameter looks more like this:

```
public Uri RelativeUri
{
    get
    {
        List<string> partsOfUri = new List<string>();
        this.getParts(this, parts);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.Root);
        parts.Reverse();
        parts.ForEach(p =>
        {
            sb.Append("/");
            sb.Append(System.Uri.EscapeDataString(p)); // to avoid problems with '/' in parts
        });
        return new System.Uri(sb.ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

The parts are labels that can have slashes, accents, spaces, etc. Somewhere else in my solution, I call `MyObject.RelativeUri.ToString()` and I got this strange behaviour.

`Encoding.Default` returns `System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding`

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code.

It correctly gives the following result:

```
root/something%20with%20spac%C3%A9s%20and%20acc%C3%A8nts
```

Can you share that how and where you are trying to run this code?

Just for your reference, `Encoding.Default` gives me the following result:

```
System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding
```

Comment: I get the same result as OP. `sb2.ToString()` produces the expected output, but the following call to `result2.ToString()` does not - thats where the encoding of spaces and special chars are undone.

Comment: I too get `System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding` when calling `Encoding.Default`

Comment: OP has both a grave accent and an acute accent in `sb2`. Having only grave accent(s) produces the expected output. Maybe only a subset of characters can be properly handled

Comment: @hlintrup even if i call to `result2.ToString()` I get the expected output.

Comment: @hlintrup I'm using the exact string `something with spacés and accènts` provided by the OP

Comment: I just edited my post to give more details about encoding and where this code is run. Thanks for your help!